# Am trying to create an item in the cart for a Big Commerce store and it keeps redirecting to the item page I just left

Tags: bigcommerce

We are working on behalf of a Big Commerce store owner and are trying to add items to the shopping cart by posting the same data that the regular item page posts, except it is done by an external program on another server.  This is because we intercept the post (which is done via a postbackurl on an iframe included in the item page that allows the customer to customize the item)... and then repost the same data to the cart.

This was working in our test store but not in the client store.  I'm wondering if the difference is that when the item page posts, the Origin header is of course from that store.  WHen I post it from my program, the origin header is different.  How can I tell what the real issue is?

Is there a setting in Big Commerce that allows posts from another origin?
Or, how do I add a store product from an external program into the Big Commerce cart?

Thanks,
Cindy

---

Yes, the product has options... I am not posting them in the form below but it makes sense that I should.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitform() {             
       document.forms["redirectpost"].submit();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="submitform();">

    <form name="redirectpost" method="post" action="http://eystudios8.mybigcommerce.com/cart.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="211">
        <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" vale="">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_id" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="qty[]" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="ProductFields[1]" value="<?php echo $docsession; ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="" style="display:none;">
    </form>
```

I also have a configurable field I am attempting to post the docsession to. 
Cindy

Adding this question:
I see that I need to post the options in my form - how do I know what field name to call each option?  There are about 15 options I need to forward to the cart page.  Cindy

Comment: Can you show us some code so we know what you are referencing? Also, any chance the product you are trying to push into the car has product options?

Comment: have you tried to use remote.php

Comment: Miglio, what is remote.php?  Cindy